# How to compare C++ string using qsort in c?

Tags: c++, string, qsort

I tried to learn the qsort function of the c-library `stdlib`. This is provided even in `c++`. But i dont understand how to use them for sorting `c++` strings. I am not sure of what the parameters should be for the `sizeof()` operator and whether my `compare_str` code is right. I tried this code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    #include<string>

    int compare_str( const void *a, const void *b){
       string  obj = (const char*)a;
       string obj1 = (const char*)b;
       return obj.compare(obj1);
    }
    int main(){
        string obj[4] = {"fine", "ppoq", "tri", "get"};
        qsort(obj, 4, sizeof(obj[0].length()), compare_str);
        for( int i=0; i<4; i++)
            cout<<obj[i]<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

My output was:

```
ppoq
tri
get
fine
```

I am not able to make out the error. Please help.

Comment: I am very suspicious of this part "sizeof(obj[0].length())"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot and must not use `qsort` on an array of `std::string`s. The elements must be of **trivial type**, which strings are not, and thus the behaviour is undefined. From 25.5/4 ("qsort"):

> The behavior is undefined unless the objects in the array pointed to by `base` are of trivial type.

The reason is that `qsort` will `memcpy` the array elements around, which is not possible for C++ objects in general (unless they're sufficiently trivial).

---

If you do have a trivial type, you can use this generic qsorter-comparator (but of course this is a terrible idea, and the inlined `std::sort` is always preferable):

```
template <typename T>
int qsort_comp(void const * pa, void const * pb)
{
    static_assert<std::is_trivial<T>::value, "Can only use qsort with trivial type!");

    T const & a = *static_cast<T const *>(pa);
    T const & b = *static_cast<T const *>(pb);

    if (a < b)  { return -1; }
    if (b < a)  { return +1; }
    return 0;
}
```

*Use:* `T arr[N]; qsort(arr, N, sizeof *arr, qsort_comp<T>);`

*Don't use this. Use `std::sort` instead.*

Comment: Any indications that this will ever break for a string?

Comment: (+1) True. I forgot to mention this in my answer - and it is the most important thing in this case.

Comment: @themel Any indications it will never break (except that it *"should work"* or *"works for you"*)? **Knowing** that something **won't ever** break is far better than **assuming** that something **should** never break.

Comment: Well, it's really "knowing that it won't break because you know how this is implemented in every compiler the asker will ever see" vs "knowing that it won't break because there's a standard that says it won't". Both kinds of knowledge have their uses, but when your program breaks, pointing out that it's a standard violation won't make it run.

Comment: @themel: In this case I think it's pretty clear-cut: The question must be of pure academic interest and cannot possibly come from any real codebase, since it would be absolutely idiotic to attempt such a thing, with absolutely no reason not to use `std::sort`. Therefore, there's very limited value in debating how much or how little this would break on real compilers...

Comment: @themel I agree about ignoring trivial UB and IB cases, like evil `reinterpret_cast`s, union aliasing or twos-complement integers when the situation requires and  allows it, but I won't ever make any assumptions about the implementation of something as abstract as `std::string` or `qsort` (which of course shouldn't copy/destroy anything and only shuffle around existing data, but well).

Comment: Actually, people do this, and yes, it breaks: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/pull/6767

Answer (score 10):

Better be C++ oriented and use std::sort for your array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

   std::string obj[4] = {"fine", "ppoq", "tri", "get"};
   std::sort(obj, obj + 4);
   std::copy(obj, obj + 4, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

AFAIK - `std::sort` uses quick sort.

[UPDATE] See comments, std::sort is not always pure quick sort.

[UPDATE2]

If you want to learn qsort - change `std::string` to `const char*` and define function based on `strcmp`. Remember that qsort passes pointers to elements in an array - so dereference `const void*` to get `const char*`. See:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_cstr(const void* c1, const void* c2) 
{ 
   return strcmp(*(const char**)(c1), *(const char**)(c2)); 
}

int main() {

   const char* obj[4] = {"fine", "ppoq", "tri", "get"};
   qsort(obj, 4, sizeof(obj[0]), compare_cstr);
   std::copy(obj, obj + 4, std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: In the implementations I've looked at, `std::sort` was actually an introsort (which basically *is* a Quicksort, except that it tracks the recursion depth, and if it goes too deep uses a heapsort instead).

Comment: @Jerry Seems my knowledge does not go as far as yours ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you give qsort an array of C++ strings. In your comparison function, you seem to except C strings, since you cast them to (const char*).

Also, the third parameter of qsort, the size of data, you actually give wrong value. sizeof(obj[0].length()) will result in sizeof(size_t), which is obviously wrong. sizeof(obj[0]) would be more correct, but remember that qsort won't call copy constructor of string, which might lead to problems.

I would suggest not to use qsort with C++ strings.

See answer provided by PiotrNycz for correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `std::sort` template function provided by the C++ standard library (in the `<algorithm>` header file). By default, `std::sort` uses the less than comparison operator to order elements (`std::string` already implements `operator<`). If you need to specify an ordering condition (for example, case insensitive string compare), `std::sort` allows you to specify an ordering function object.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool caseInsensitiveOrdering(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
   // return true if lowercase lhs is less than lowercase rhs
}

int main()
{
    std::string names[] = {"chuck", "amy", "bob", "donna"};
    size_t nameCount = sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]);

    // Sort using built-in operator<
    std::sort(names, names + nameCount);

    // Sort using comparison function
    std::sort(names, names + nameCount, &caseInsensitiveOrdering);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error is in the declaration of the size in `qsort`. What is expected is the size of a member, which is, in your case, a string. So you want to use:

```
qsort(obj, 4, sizeof(string), compare_str);
```

However, you need to work with pointer to string, rather than strings themselves. Then, the code should look like:

```
int compare_str( const void *a, const void *b){
   const string*  obj = (const string*)a;
   const string* obj1 = (const string*)b;
   return obj->compare(*obj1);
}

// ...

string* obj[4] = { new string("fine"), new string("ppoq"),
                   new string("tri"), new string("get") };
qsort(obj, 4, sizeof(string*), compare_str);
// And delete the objects
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i) delete obj[i];
```

Comment: What the...? Ok, at least the code is correct now, at least if you change `obj` and `obj1` to be `const std::string**`s.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#include<string>

int compare_str( const void *a, const void *b){
   string* obj = (string*)a;
   string* obj1 = (string*)b;
   return obj->compare(*obj1);
}
int main(){
    string obj[4] = {"fine", "ppoq", "tri", "get"};
    qsort(obj, 4, sizeof(string), compare_str);
    for( int i=0; i<4; i++)
        cout<<obj[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed: undefined behavior often looks like it "works". And it will continue to work, until you do that critical demo for your most important customer, and then it will fall on its face.

Comment: -1 - *"works for me"* is never a proof of correctness in C++, especially when the UB is as obvious as in this case (and the alternatives are **far** superior in each aspect).